# Insert Data from multiple tables into a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

```
INSERT INTO MonthlyFee(StudentID, ClassTypeID, Fee, MonthID,
          [Year], IsDefaulter, FeeStatus, CreatedDate) 
SELECT StudentID, ClassTypeID FROM ClassRollNo
```

I want to set the following values (mostly hardcoded parameters): MonthID 1, Year 2015, IsDefaulter FALSE, FeeStatus 0  and CreatedDate GETDATE().

Comment: Your heading says "from multiple tables" - but you select from a single one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hard code those values in same `select` statement in order of insert `column list`.Try this syntax

```
INSERT INTO MonthlyFee
            (StudentID,
             ClassTypeID,
             Fee,
             MonthID,
             [Year],
             IsDefaulter,
             FeeStatus,
             CreatedDate)
SELECT StudentID,
       ClassTypeID,
       100, -- You missed
       1,
       2015,
       'false',
       0,
       Getdate()
FROM   ClassRollNo
```

**Note :** You missed Fee column i have hard coded

Answer (score 0):

Use the same query and the values you described:

```
INSERT INTO MonthlyFee(StudentID, ClassTypeID,Fee,MonthID,
      [Year],IsDefaulter,FeeStatus,CreatedDate) 
SELECT StudentID, ClassTypeID, 0, 1, 2015, 0, 0, GETDATE() FROM ClassRollNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO MonthlyFee(StudentID, ClassTypeID,MonthID,
          [Year],IsDefaulter,FeeStatus,CreatedDate) 
 SELECT StudentID, ClassTypeID,1,2013,false,0,getdate() FROM ClassRollNo
```